# Result not showing in the corresponding paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

For some unknown reason(console doesn't show it), it's not showing the response to the input like "the answer is right" or "the answer is either empty or wrong"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    
    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <h1>Hi there!</h1>     
    <p id="check1">
     The result will be shown here
    </p>     
    
    
    <input type="text" id="word0" placeholder="enter what you heard " /> 
    <script>     
    function check()
    { 
      var arr=["cat","dog","fish","husky","jasmine"]
      
      var answer1=document.getElementById("word0").value
     
        if (answer1==arr[0] )
         {document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML="The answer is right"}
      
      else {document.getElementById("check1").innerHTML="The answer is either empty or wrong, please reenter"
              var answercat=[]
              answercat[0]=prompt("enter the word cat for the first time:")
               if(answercat[0]!="cat")
                 {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
              answercat[1]=prompt("enter the word cat for the second time:")
                   if(answercat[1]!="cat")
                 {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
              answercat[2]=prompt("enter the word cat for the third time:")
                  if(answercat[2]!="cat")
                 {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
              answercat[3]=prompt("enter the word cat for the fourth time:")
                  if(answercat[3]!="cat")
                 {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
              answercat[4]=prompt("enter the word cat for the fifth time:")
                  if(answercat[4]!="cat")
                 {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
              
             }
    }
 
    
    
    </script>
    
    <button onclick="check()">
       
    </button>
    <p>
      I'm your cool new webpage. Made with <a href="https://glitch.com">Glitch</a>!
    </p>

    <!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
          to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
    <div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
    <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Who need to actually call the `check()` function. Also, why are you passing an `answer` parameter, if you're not going to use it?

Comment: The function is not being called when the input changes.

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/rural-astronaut?path=index.html:57:5 .   The complete version is here. Still not showing after calling the function

Comment: Please always post your code right here in your question. I've copied your code over and it appears to work properly.

Comment: @JiangYuxin, Whether you will check for result once the check button is clicked?

Comment: Yes I check the answer once the button is clicked

Comment: https://codepen.io/sobczi/pen/NWWepEj

Comment: @sobczi I don't really get it but thank you for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add event listener to the input then call the `check()` function on input.

If you are using any `HTML` elements then use `.innerHTML` otherwise use `textContent`..

```js
function check()
{ 
  const arr=["cat","dog","fish","husky","jasmine"]
  
  const  answer1 = document.getElementById("word0").value
 
    if (answer1 === arr[0] )
     {
  document.getElementById("check1").textContent="The answer is right"
     }
  
  else {
    document.getElementById("check1").textContent="The answer is either empty or wrong, please reenter"
          var answercat=[]
          answercat[0]=prompt("enter the word cat for the first time:")
           if(answercat[0]!="cat")
             {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
          answercat[1]=prompt("enter the word cat for the second time:")
               if(answercat[1]!="cat")
             {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
          answercat[2]=prompt("enter the word cat for the third time:")
              if(answercat[2]!="cat")
             {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
          answercat[3]=prompt("enter the word cat for the fourth time:")
              if(answercat[3]!="cat")
             {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
          answercat[4]=prompt("enter the word cat for the fifth time:")
              if(answercat[4]!="cat")
             {prompt("you entered wrong word, enter the word 'cat' one more time")}
          
         }
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click',check)
```

```html
<h1>Hi there!</h1>     
<p id="check1">
 The result will be shown here
</p>     


<input type="text" id="word0" placeholder="enter what you heard " /> 

<button>
   Check
</button>

<!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
      to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
<div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
<script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
```

Comment: Close, but if you use the `input` event, the function would get called upon each character input and therefore show the "incorrect" message before you were even done typing in the answer. In this case, the `change` event is the way to go.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Here is the more complete version of my question:https://glitch.com/edit/#!/rural-astronaut?path=index.html:57:5 .   It's not working even though I called the function

Comment: @ScottMarcus, Yuo are right, but OP mention about how he need the result.

Comment: The OP doesn't say he wants the `input` event. He just means that the answer (based on the input) doesn't show up.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, Yes now he edits the question and he wants to check it on button click it seems will edit my answer..

Comment: Hi, Could you see the bug here? I am so confused because it's supposed to be simple codes

Comment: Hi thanks! Now I have another question: how can I make the result appear in the paragraph before the prompt box?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Because when I run the code snippet the prompt goes before the result, but I want the user to see their result first

Comment: @JiangYuxin, You mean before opening the prompt you need to display the wron result first then prompt should open?

Comment: Yes exactly, is it possible to do that?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan .  for clarification I just want it to display " the answer is wrong" and then prompt opens, no need to display the wrong answer

Comment: @JiangYuxin, whether this is you expectation https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/JjjwWmz ?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan . Yes exactly but I have not learnt settimeout method. Do you mind try it here?  https://glitch.com/edit/#!/reinvented-ringer?path=index.html:199:6

Comment: @JiangYuxin, Take a look at here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sugar-stove?path=index.html:100:15 .. Settimeout is used to wait for the time mentioned then it will execute..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Hi，thank you but it doesn't seem to be working ?

Comment: @JiangYuxin, Then something wrong with your implementation and I don't know about this glitch so take up my solution try to figure out what you are trying to do in your application..

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't even call this function.
If you want to call it everytime input is changed set `onchange=check(this.value)` to your input.

Comment: While you are right that there needs to be an event handler set up. Please [don't advocate inline HTML event attributes, like `onXyz`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991). It's not 1995, JavaScript belongs separated from HTML and events are bound with `.addEventListener()`.